# Domain and range of a floor function

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions, ceiling-and-floor-functions

$$f(x)=\sqrt{4[x]-[4x]}$$ what is the domain and range of f(x)? 
I tried to plot it ,and saw $$d_f=[n,n+0.25)\\R_f={0}$$ but I can't get there  .
Help me to find them please . [x]=floor function .

Comment: HInt: you can write $$x=n+p\\n\in \mathbb{z} \\0\leq p<1$$

Comment: How can I use this notation  ?

Answer (score 6):

suppose $x=n+p\\0\leq p<1$
$$\quad{f(x)=\sqrt{4[x]-[4x]}=\\\sqrt{4[n+p]-[4(n+p)]}=\\
\sqrt{4n-[4n+4p]}=\\
\sqrt{4n-4n-[4p]}=\\
\sqrt{-[4p]}\\\implies-[4p]\geq 0\\ [4p]\leq 0 \implies [4p]=0 \\0 \leq 4p<1 \\0\leq p <\frac{1}{4} \to\\D_{f(x)}=[n,n+\frac{1}{4}) ,n \in \mathbb{Z}\\R_{f(x)}=\{\sqrt{0}\}=\{0\} }$$